# How to have 'distinct' in having clause

Tags: sql, informix

EDIT: This is an example relation! I need it to work on a bigger relation so no workarounds!

So I was given a simple task and at first I didn't see what could possibly be wrong and now I just don't understand why it doesnt work.

Lets say I have a table of people and their friends and I want to select the ones who have 2 or more friends.

**people**

```
------------------------------
|person  | friend | relation |
|-----------------------------
|ana     | jon    | friend   |
|ana     | jon    | lover    |
|ana     | phillip| friend   |
|ana     | kiki   | friend   |
|mary    | jannet | friend   |
|mary    | jannet | lover    |
|peter   | july   | friend   |
```

---

I would want to do a

```
 SELECT person FROM people GROUP BY person HAVING count(distinct friend) > 1;
```

and get

```
-------
| ana |
-------
```

But I get a syntax error when using the '`distinct`' in the HAVING clause.
I understand that the '`distinct`' is a part of the projection clause but
how do I make '`count`' only count distinct entries without an additional subquery or something?

EDIT: The best I could come up with is:

```
SELECT tmp.person FROM (SELECT person, count(distinct friend) 
             AS numfriends FROM people GROUP BY person) AS tmp 
       WHERE tmp.numfriends > 1;
```

Comment: Mysql or sqlserver ?

Comment: Well it's rather ibm informix but I thought it would be the same in any sql db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the doc

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0162.htm

> The condition in the HAVING clause cannot include a DISTINCT or UNIQUE
>   aggregate expression.

An work-around would be to have the count distinct in the select

```
SELECT 
person,
count(distinct friend) as f_count
FROM people 
GROUP BY person 
HAVING f_count > 1;
```

**UPDATE :**

Checked the document and found the facts

> The HAVING clause is evaluated before the SELECT - so the server
>   doesn't yet know about that alias.

So to achieve the goal it could be done as

```
select
person,
f_count
from(
 SELECT 
 person,
 count(distinct friend) as f_count
 FROM people
 GROUP BY person 
)x
where f_count > 1
```

Comment: Hmm. It says f_count is not found in any table in the query

Comment: Thats interesting.. I was looking at the doc and there is nothing mentioned about the above case. Ideally the having will be evaluated after the selection is done. May be it does not support that. But its not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Does it maybe filter with having before calculating entries for the new relation?

Comment: Perhaps yes , thats the reason its not identifying the alias. Try using count(*) in the having clause.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write it like this

```
SELECT person
FROM people
WHERE relation = 'friend'
GROUP BY person 
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

just check this.

```
declare @t table(person varchar(50),  Friend VARCHAR(50), relation VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES('ana', 'jon','friend')
,('ana', 'jon','lover')
,('ana', 'phillip','friend')
,('ana', 'kiki','friend')
,('mary', 'jannat','friend')
,('mary', 'jannat','lover')


SELECT DISTINCT PERSON FROM 
(
    SELECT person FROM @t GROUP BY person HAVING count(friend) > 1
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way via using more group by's -

```
select cust_xref_id
from(
select cust_xref_id,cm11
from temp_nippon_cust
group by cust_xref_id,cm11
) temp
group by cust_xref_id
having count(cm11) > 1
```